# When I add data to the Redux store, result is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I really don't understand how to add data to my store, nothing complicated I don't understand, I looked at a lot of tutorials and resources but nothing works, the best I have is null in my store with the current userReducer.

My store :

[image]

My userReducer :

```js
import {GET_USER, GET_USERS, ADD_USER} from "../actions/userAction";

export default function userReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_USER:
            return action.payload

        case GET_USERS:
            return action.payload


        case ADD_USER:
            return [
                ...state,
                action.payload
            ]

        default :
            return state
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

---**EDIT**---

```js
        case GET_USERS:
            return {
                users: action.payload
            }
        case ADD_USER:
            return {
                users: [
                    ...state.users,
                    action.payload
                ]
            }
```

Comment: `GET_USER` replaces the entire users array with the `action.payload`, which is probably not what you want.  The `ADD_USER` appends to an array which looks more correct.  If `state` is an array then the initial value should be `[]` instead of `{}`.

Comment: Can you print `action` to see what it is?

Comment: Please add code of action creators ```GET_USER```, ```GET_USERS```, ```ADD_USER```

Comment: finally I found, all that was missing was the braces, thanks for your help :)